# Template file not recognized when moved to module theme folder

Tags: theming

I have a template file in my custom module folder which I am using to theme a form. Everything works fine when the template file is in the root of my custom module folder. However, I would like to move this template file to another sub-folder in my custom module folder, so that I can basically put all the template files in one folder. My directory structure is such that in the root of the my custom module folder I have (/sites/all/modules/mycustommodule):

mycustommodule.module
mycustommodule.info
mycustommodule.install
mycustommodule_admin.inc

In /sites/all/modules/mycustommodule/mycustomthemes:
mycustommodule-example-form.tpl.php
mycustommodule-example2-form-tpl.php

This is my hook_theme:

```
'mycustommodule_example_form' => array(
  'template' => 'mycustommodule-example-form',
  'file' => 'mycustommodule_admin.inc', 
  'render element' => 'form',
),
```

I would like to know what I would need to do to make the path clear to Drupal that the template file is in that sub-folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `'template' => 'subfolder/mycustommodule-example-form'`.

Answer (score 1):

or you can move free to your theme's templates directory. Drupal seeks tpl files recursively inside theme directories. you  may store your mycustommodule-example-form.tpl.php to

```
mytheme/templates/mymoduletemplates/mycustommodule-example-form.tpl.php
```

or

```
mytheme/templates/mycustommodule-example-form.tpl.php
```

but this will not work for another theme